# What will resolve the WebDriverError: Connection refused error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I cannot run Protractor tests locally, a few days ago I could but now I cannot. I even rebooted Ubuntu. Here are my versions:

```
$cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5
$node --version
v6.8.0
$npm list -g|grep protractor
└─┬ protractor@4.0.9
$webdriver-manager status
[13:49:58] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 2.53.1 [default]
[13:49:58] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.22 [default]
[13:49:58] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[13:49:58] I/status - appium is not present
$/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version
Google Chrome 54.0.2840.59 unknown
```

Here is the stack trace https://paste.fedoraproject.org/449363/35548414/

How can I fix this; are there other versions should I check?

Comment: The stack trace has gone missing.  That makes this question pretty useless: we don't know what problem the solutions solve!

Comment: @ddreian can you update the 404'd link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something broke with the Chrome update yesterday. Get the newest chromedriver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and replace your current Protractor chromedriver (should be 2.22) with the newest one (2.24).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your fast reply. I put the latest chromedriver in /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver, I added it to my PATH variable and I marked it as executable and it still does not work. It throws the same stack trance. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! I moved the newly downloaded chromedriver in /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22

THANK YOU!! :D

Answer (score 6):

Just installing version 2.24 didn't work for me: it kept using the old version (2.21 in my case). To fix I first reinstalled a clean protractor and then updated the webdriver-manager to version 2.24:

```
# npm install -g protractor
# webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24
```

More info about the bug: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3640

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows. Like [W4pp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377594/w4pp) webdriver-manager was still trying to use 2.22 even if the executable didn't exist. My workaround is to explicitly use 2.24 instead of 2.22:

```
> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24  
> webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.24
```

Do an optional: `> webdriver-manager clean` before the above two commands to remove 2.22