# Selenium WebDriver: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, mean-stack

I'm running npm test on mean.js version 4.2 and it's giving me a "connection refused" error on the protractor e2e tests. I tried updating selenium like [this says to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019066/webdrivererror-connection-refused) Right now it's version 2.27 and the other Stack Overflow post says 2.24. Did the chrome driver break again?

```
Running "protractor:e2e" (protractor) task
webdriver-manager path: /Users/tdiddy/meaning42/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.30:53658/wd/hub

/Users/tdiddy/meaning42/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at new bot.Error (/Users/tdiddy/meaning42/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context, to answer your question, I believe chromedriver 2.27 is not used...this is why:

"Selenium standalone server started at http:" means that you have started the selenium standalone server with the local driver provider. When you start Protractor version 4 (grunt-protractor-runner uses Protractor version ^4.0.0) with a local driver provider, the chromedriver used is the version stated in the webdriver-manager's configuration. Just because you download 2.27 does not mean that Protractor will use Protractor 2.27 when launching locally.

There are two ways to use chromedriver 2.27:

- You'll need Protractor 5 to [use the last downloaded binary when launching a local driver provider](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3922). Download chromedriver 2.27 with `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.27` then launch your Protractor test.
- Do not use the local driver provider. Download your binaries with `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.27` then launch your selenium standalone server with `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.27`. Once you have started that, launch it with `seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"` in your configuration.

Why you are getting `Connection refused` could be because the Chrome version you are running at the chromedriver version you are using are not compatible. I would suggest trying a combination of the two suggestions: use a `seleniumAddress`in your configuration with Protractor 5.0.0. If this combination fails, please feel free to open up an [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and updating chromedriver to v2.32 via brew (`brew update chromedriver`) fixed it for me